# Permissions denied from adding files to server

Tags: ubuntu, github, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using [dploy.io](http://dploy.io) to deploy github files to my live server but I keep getting an error regarding permissions.

I'm on Ubuntu (14.04) and /var/www/html user:group is set to `www-data:www-data` to work with HHVM and Nginx. Is there a way that I could add an existing user, let's say `chris` to be able to add files to that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add chris to the www-data group as follows. Use usermod with the following flags

```
usermod -a -G [group-name] [user-name]
```

Or

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data chris
```

Hope that helps,
Pat